# .NET Framework 4 and Fatal Execution Engine Error in WPF after calling an Interop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, interop, fatal-error

I am working on a WPF application, .NET Framework 4. 
The application passes a sample array on to a C++ library via Interop for some statistical analysis. Sometimes, just with certain input values, I get a "Fatal Execution Engine Error".

In order to find out what's going on, I've created a small WPF test application. Apparently data are properly passed back to the WPF application and the crash occurs even after the returned values are displayed in a TextBox (WPF) (funny thing is that the exception happens after moving the mouse pointer for a bit!).

I've also tried to test the same C++ library in a small Console test application. And in this case I am getting a different behaviour: when the COM library gets called, the Console application just stops and quits. No exception, no errors.

I was reading about a similar problem, but that was with .NET Framework 2 and .NET Framework 3.5.

Could you advice me on what my alternatives are in order to track this error down? What do you suggest in order to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Gianluca

Comment: You could try to call the C++ library from a simple C++ project with the same values, so at least you know if the error is with the interop (most likely, easy to mess something up) or simply with the library.

Comment: Most likely there is a bug inside your C++ component. Could you isolate it in a different process or a web service?